# ASP.NET MVC Controller recommendation for LINQ DataContext instantiation place

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, datacontext

How should I instantiate the datacontext (entity fw) in a MVC Controller:

- a) as a property in class
- b) as a field in class
- c) as a variable in Action
- d) as abstract away your DbContext with the Repository pattern

In WebForms I would use c), because b) would maintain the db object state across events, which is usually not what I want.

I actually never used a).

Comment: d) abstract away your `DbContext` with the Repository pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to start by saying that I 100% agree with @jrummell in that the DbContext should be instantiated.  However, if you aren't going to do that, I would use a private readonly field and provide two constructors:

```
public MyController() : this(new DbContext()) { }

public MyController(DbContext context)
{
   this._dbContext = context;
}
```

This way you can still inject a DbContext for testing.

Comment: Why is this exclude the repositopry? The dependency injection patter expexts the datacontext from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

you should probably make use of the `repository pattern` with `dependency injection`
passing in the context through the constructor
and with it you will have to use a toll like [Unity](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/254091/Implementing-Microsoft-Unity-Design-Pattern) to Inject the Context in the `constructor`

Answer (score 0):

Have a  private variable which is an object of your Repositary Interface and  Instantiate it in your constructor. you can use that in all your action methods now

```
public class ItemsController : Controller
{
    private IRepositary repo;

    public ItemsController()
    {
        repo = new Repositary(new YourDBContext());
    }
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
      var item=repo.GetItemById(id);
      //if needed, map to your view model and return that to the view
     //  instead of model object to the view
      return View(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to use a persistence agnostic data access pattern such as the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). The basic idea is to create controller specific interfaces that abstract away your data access.

```
public interface ICatalogRepository : IRepository
{
  Category GetCategory(int id);
  Product GetProduct(int id);

  void Add(Product product);

  IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; }
  IEnumerable<Supplier> Suppliers { get; }
}

public class CatalogRepository : ICatalogRepository
{
  private YourDbContext _db;

  public CatalogRepository(YourDbContext db)
  {
     _db = db;
  }

  public Category GetCategory(int id)
  {
     return _db.Categories.Find(id);
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Then you would use an instance of `ICatalogRepository` in your controller - it won't have any knowledge of Entity Framework. See [Using the unit of work-per-request pattern in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/12/using-the-unit-of-work-per-request-pattern-in-aspnet-mvc/) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a very small application or has only a few users; or the lifetime of the application is short, I would never put the any data access "like" code in a UI layer. You just made a design decision that will impact the maintainability and testability of the application.

I like the idea of using a repository pattern with dependency injection - this has proven to work very well. In fact, the current application I work on processes over 11 billion web requests each month against 7 different database instances of MySQL using this pattern.

Another suggestion, implement a service/business layer under the UI. One of the responsibilities of this layer is to provide an API for business processing and database transactions. I usually implement the repository in the business layer, but it references and uses a data access layer component for the actual database-specific transactions. This way you have an abstraction of data access in your business layer - this is a good thing, because a long-lived application will many changes in data access. With this nice abstraction in place, you can use Entity Framework or any other database technology, like NoSQL. Also, using DI, interface/abstract classes allow you to inject the instance of the "repository" into the business component - this certainly improves the testability of your application: so fully unit test your application with a mocking framework (NUnit + Moq).

Hope this helps.